# Which data structure should I use for maintaining this information?

Tags: java, data-structures

Hello guys I have two entities connected with each other with a relationship, like this:

**Entity A is known to entity B, and entity B knows entity A.**

Which is the most efficient data structure that I can use in order to maintain this information?

I was think of having 2 hashmaps with key the entity's A key and value a list for each B entity that knows about A, and another one with key entity B's key etc. But I was wondering if I can use just one data structure.

I am aiming for performance in speed rather than space, so it doesn't matter if it's big as long as it's fast.

Comment: No possibility for *composition*?

Comment: See how many to many relationship is managed in hibernate.

Comment: I don't think this is solvable in such general form. It is true that we could suggest one structure or another, but they'd all be equally valid since we don't know who will use relation info and for what purpose. In certain situations it is perfectly reasonable to model this as a Map<Entity, Set<Entity>>, Multimap<Entity, Entity>, or as private field on Entity itself - we don't know.

Comment: Is it always symmetrical?

Comment: @Sentry symmetrical in what sense? That all objects are known or know about at least one?

Comment: Symmetrical in the sense that "If A knows B, then B knows A" and vice versa. Or is it possible that A knows B, but B doesn't know A?

Comment: Also, you say you're aiming for performance. But you didn't say if you mean read or write performance or both. Could you elaborate on that more?

Comment: @Sentry Ah should have guessed sorry, yes it is always symmetrical. I was talking about read speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you want to use a Datastructure?
It is a "normal" bidirectional association between the two objects.

```
class A {
    B b;
    ....
    // Perhaps you can do somthinkg like this to maintain consitsncy
    void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        b.a = a;
}
class B {
    A a;
    ....
}
```

Comment: yes sure, then I should have 2 lists, one containing class A objects and another one containing class B objects. Thus 2 lists. Is it possible to utilize one data structure instead?

Comment: In Apache Commons Lang there is a Pair http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've mentioned the focus is on speed, this really comes down to how you need to acess the data, ie  what question do you need to ask of the data structure.

For example, if you only need to ask the question, "does X know about Y", or "does Y know about X" then you only need one hash map. or hash set,
as long as you can produce a decent hashCode() implementation for a pair of them
(see further before for a sample hashCode implementation though probably not a good one and it's been many years since I used Java)

ie with a set

```
class Item extends Pair {
  Item(A,B)
  // override hashCode() and equals() methods as necessary 
}

hashset<Item> relationships;
relationships.add(new Item(A,B))
relationships.add(new Item(B,C))

if( ! relationship.contains (new Item(B,A)))
   // print "b does not know a"
```

or a map:

```
HashMap<Item,Boolean> relationships;
relationships.put(Item(A,B),True)
....
```

but, if you need to look at one entity and then find all the things that it knows about, then a graph structure is better.

If you're building a one time data set that doesn't need much flexibility You can implement a graph as a single linked list though, containing all edges from a starting point, and have a hash (by object key) pointing to the first edge in each list of known items.

For example, untested pseudocode, not correct java

```
Class Item {
  Entity first
  Entity second
  Item next;
  Item prior;
  Item(x,y) { first = x; second = y; }
  Item Join(nextItem) { 
    next = nextItem; next.prior = this; return next; 
  }
  // override hashCode and equals() but don't use 'next' or prior as part of the hash calculation or equals comparison

  //this is just for example, not sure if this is a good hash
  long hashCode() { return a. hashCode() & b.hashCode(); }
}

class Graph extends HashSet<Item> {

  Bool containsRelationship(Entity x, Entity y) {
     return contains(new Item(x,y))
   }
   Bool isRcognisedEntity(Entity x) {
     return contains(new Item(x,x))
  }
  Item getRelationships(Entity x) {
      Item ret = get(new Item(x,x))
       if ret is not null
         return ret.next // return the first entity x knows, other than itself
       else 
         return null // nothing known
  }

  Item addEntity(Entity e, Entity[] e_knows) {
     Item first = new item (e,e)
     add(first)
     Item lastItem = first
     for k in e_knows
         lastItem = lastItem.join(new item(e,k))
         add(lastItem)
     return first
  }
}

Entity a;
Entity b;
Entity c;
Graph g;
g.addEntity(a, {b,c})
g.addEntity(b, {c})
g.addEntity(c,{ a,b,c})

if g.contains(item(a,b))
   Print "a knows b"

c_knows = g.getRelationships(c)

while c_knows is not null
   Print "c knows " + c_knows.second
   c_knows = c.next
```

So you see this way with just one Set, you can ask "does x know y" and also "who does x know", at the expense of some memory overhead from the next/prior attributes (you might only need one)

If instead of a common Entity base class, you have two separate classes A and B, then you could do this instead with Object, and cast the results as necessary, within routines of the Graph class to provide type safety.

For example

```
class Item {
  Object first;
  Object second;
 ...
}
class Graph {
 // as above except use Object instead of Entity, and make the methods protected not public
}
class ABGraph extends Graph {

   Iterator getRelationships(A a) {
     return new B_Itemterator(super.getRelationships(a));
   }
   void addRelationships(A a,B[] b_knows) {
     super.getRelationships( a, b_knows)
   }
   // Similar functions for B
}
class A_ItemIterator implements Java.collections...Iterator<A> {
  A_ItemIterator(Item i) { this.i = I }
  bool hasNext() { return i.next !=  null; }
  A next() { item n = i.next; I = n; return n; }
}

// similar iterator class for B_ItemIterator

ABGraph g;
A a;
B b1;
B b2;
g.addRelationships(a, new B[]{b1,b2})

if g.contains (a,b1) // should still work 

Iterator<B> i= g.getRelationships(a)
while(i.hasNext())
  print " thing "+ a + " of type A knows about " + b.next() + "of type B'
```